# Is there something like Python help function in Fsharp interactive?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Using Python in command line you can write help(function) to see docstring.
Is there something similar in Fsharp for fsi?

Do you have any tips and tricks for working in fsi anyway?

What is even possible to find out without using IDE? Just from interactive session.

EDIT:
This question is actually addressed to Python guys who know Fsharp as well. I guess MS guys relying on their VS might find my question pretty strange :)

So far it seems that my question has simple answer: NO.

EXAMPLE:
Lets say you are logged to remote computer via console. I dont know whether this is typical or even possible scenario. For some reason I started *fsi* and now what? Am I lost or do I have some chances to get some help from fsi directly

DISCLAMER:
I know Scott Wlaschins **fsharpforfunandprofit.com** pretty well. But his example is dedicated to C# users. Pythonists have different workflow.

Comment: Can you clarify - you would like to _only_ use FSI, no IDE of any sort?

Comment: I started to write an answer for this but this question is so open that it is hard to give a helpful answer. These might help. [Visual Studio Intellisense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx), [Visual Studio Object Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf(v=vs.90).aspx), or [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/)

Comment: Basically you have to change the way you think from Python with [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) to F# with static typing, [.Net Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045(v=vs.110).aspx), [F# core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353567(v=vs.100).aspx), and extensions.

Comment: Also, this SO thread on [F# interactive autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619033/f-interactive-autocomplete) could be helpful.

Comment: Of interest: [Using F# to explore and develop interactively](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work/#explore-net-interactively)

Comment: The short answer is no. If you need quick help from the console, PowerShell's Get-Member could work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Simple introspection can be done by *typeof <_>* or *typedefof<_>*.

For example:

> typeof<*System.Console*>;;

In fsi you can use TAB completation, but apperantly just from command line. It is not working in my Xamarin.

Neat trick is to run:

> fsi --use:yourfile.fsx

which run your file and let you test it interactively.

For more info you can use in command line **fsi.exe --help**.

Comment: `typeof<T>` works when `T` is an expression denoting a type/module (they are the same thing from the runtime point of view). If you want to get the type of an instance you can use the method `GetType`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are used to interactive python, and you like the approach, you may have a look at this F# engine for iPython Notebook:

https://github.com/fsprojects/IfSharp

Comment: That is great project, I agree! Unfortunately, I have some bug to run it. But ipython command line is not the same as jupyter. But I am satisfied with fsi right now. I discovered few things :)

Comment: @PavelHanpari there is a new branch which is supposed to be jupyter compatible. Unfortunately since it is still being developed you have to compile it manually from the repository. I tried it yesterday and it worked.

Comment: I have to try it myself again. I tried to compiled but there was some error in my case about library version. Maybe the solution might be to use Paket which should solve the problem if I understood correctly. But my .NET is broken somehow.